# How to reference a control on windows phone main page from any other non UI class?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I thought I could access a control on main page from any non ui class in same namespace by using

```
            var frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
            var startPage = frame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
```

But intellisense doesn't show up any control.

Didn't find anything on Google that's weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access your control from another class, you can either:

- Use the [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method to retrieve it:

  ```
  var myButton = (Button)startPage.FindName("myButton");
  ```
- Expose the control with a public property, and cast the page to its strong type rather than `PhoneApplicationPage`:

  In ManPage.xaml.cs:

  ```
  public Button MyButton
  {
      get
      {
          return this.myButton;
      }
  }
  ```

  In your other class:

  ```
  var frame = (PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual;
  var startPage = (MainPage)frame.Content; 

  // Here, you can use startPage.MyButton
  ```

Note that accessing a UI control from outside of the page is almost always a bad idea. You may want to re-think your application's architecture rather than doing that (the MVVM pattern can help for instance).

Comment: hi thanks for source code. I know it's bad it's just for quick learning the basics first ;)